# Buffer does not exist in my image with multer and gridfs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

so I am using multer with gridfs to store my image on mongodb and when doing req.file the buffer field does not exist so therefore i do not know how to store the image or retrieve it properly

here is my current code

this is when creating a course and uploading an image

```
const createCourse = asyncHandler(async (req,res) => {
    const {title, description, instructor, rating} = req.body;

    const existingCourse = await Course.findOne({title});

    const { filename } = req.file;
    var buffer = req.file.buffer;

    if (existingCourse) {
        throw new ConflictError('Course title is already in usage.')
    }
    console.log(req.file)
    console.log(filename)

    console.log(buffer)
    const course = await Course.create({
        title,
        description,
        instructor,
        rating,
        image: filename,
        sections: []
    });

    return res.status(201).json({_id: course.id, title: course.title})
});
```

my req.file looks like this:

```
{
  fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: 'strg.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  id: new ObjectId('659f2fd8c07837271b3faade'),
  filename: '7d039fda-381b-4668-b4f1-db2fea4542d5.jpg',
  metadata: null,
  bucketName: 'uploads',
  chunkSize: 261120,
  size: 50593,
  md5: undefined,
  uploadDate: 2024-01-11T00:01:28.330Z,
  contentType: 'image/jpeg'
}
```

and this is where i tried to retreive it:

```
const getCourseImage = async (req, res) => {
    const courseId = req.params.courseId;

    if (courseId.length !== 24) {
        throw new InvalidInputError("Invalid course Id.");
    }
      
    const course = await Course.findById(courseId);

    if (!course || !course.image) {
        return res.status(404).send('Image not found');
    }
    console.log(course.image.data.buffer)

    // const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(course.image.buffer, 'base64');

    res.contentType('image/jpeg');

    res.end(imageBuffer);
};
```

but I get an error saying the image has errors

this is my middleware for multer:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const {GridFsStorage} = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: 'mongodb://tes@localhost:27018/test',
    file: (req, file) => {
        const filename = `${uuidv4()}.${file.originalname.split('.').pop()}`;
        return {
        filename: filename,
        bucketName: 'uploads',
        };
    },
}); 


const upload = multer({ storage });

module.exports = upload;
```

and I use it in router as this for uploading and then retreiving:

```
  .post(courseValidationRules, upload.single('image'), (req, res, next) => {
    createCourse(req, res,next);
    })...
```

and this is how i retreive it in router:
`router.get('/api/courses/:courseId/image', getCourseImage);`

Been smashing my head on this, no idea how to fix it. thanks!